# Get custom values from sales_flat_order_item table in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

Get custom values from sales_flat_order_item table in magento 1.9

Anyone have idea please help

Answer (score 1):

Check product_options column in sales_flat_order_item table.

You can use order_item collection and get the value of that field like that:

```
$orderItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', '110');

foreach($orderItems as $orderItem){
    $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
    var_dump($options);
}
```